# graph.write_png doesn't work on linux( dot not found in path )- graphviz and pydot package

Tags: graphviz, pydot

I am using python through a secure shell. When I use pydot and graphviz package, it shows error [Errno 2] dot not found in path. I searched so many solutions. People suggest 'sudo apt install graphviz' or 'sudo apt-get install graphviz'. But when I use 'sudo', it shows 'username is not in the sudoers file.This incident will be reported'. I also tried to add the graphviz folder location to PATH variable using 'export PATH= $PATH:/..../lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphviz'( exact path is shown in the picture), it doesn't work. Could anyone help please? Thank you very much.
I added a screenshot. I understand that I need to add path including 'bin' [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXtx8.png), but then I didnt find the bin folder. I know what that folder looks like on Windows. When I use Filezilla to check this graphviz folder, It doesn't have this 'bin' folder.  I installed Graphviz using 'pip3 install graphviz' when I search "How do I install Graphviz on Linux?", they all say 'sodu .....', which doesn't work for me apparently . Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

1. Explicitly check if the Graphviz programs are installed.  Type **dot -V**.  Did you get a "command not found" response or something else?
2. If you are not the administrator of the Linux system, find the administrator and ask them to install Graphviz.
3. If the administrator can not or will not install Graphviz:

- You can try to build (compile) a private copy of Graphviz, but it won't be easy
- You can install WSL (Windows Subsystem Linux) and then Ubuntu and finally Graphviz on your PC, easier, but not trivial
- Mooch an old PC and install Linux on it, becoming the administrator.  Then sudo all you want.  Again lots of work.

Good luck

Comment: graphviz is installed( I used 'import graphviz' to check). So that secure shell is provided by university. I used ' pip3 install graphviz' . and you are right, when I type dot -V it does show' command not found'. Thanks for all your suggestions. I am wondering if I could use 'add to path' as I explained in the question. Could you tell me a bit more about that please?

Comment: [I do not use the Python interface to Graphviz, so this is just a guess]  While you have installed the Python interface to Graphviz, that does not necessarily mean that Graphviz itself is installed (read https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/).  Ask your administrator if the Graphviz package is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue on Debian GNU/Linux, it gone after i install this:

```
apt install graphviz
apt install graphviz-dev
```

After this you can check that it works with

```
dot -V
```

You'll get responce like `dot - graphviz version 2.43.0 (0)` if problem is fixed